# Generate typescript types for prismic

Tags: typescript, graphql, code-generation, prismic.io

While slices machine types are better supported, something that will help us is if Prismic would provide a standard Swagger/Open API or Graphql Schema so I can run swagger-typescript-api or Generate code from your GraphQL schema to get the types from the custom types of my repository into the project and manually use for each slice.

I know you provide API browser -> https://my-org.prismic.io/api/v2) and a GraphiQL -> https://my-org.prismic.io/graphql but can't really get them working with the previous code generators as I can't get the standard swagger.json or Graphql schema from your API Browser.

Getting those standard interfaces would allow me to run the generators again to get the generated ts updated anytime I made changes to the custom types in Prismic.

I tried following this link Custom Types API but it's not working.